# How to find body tag in HTML file with an unknown class?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Recently, I'm having online lessons and after each lesson, we have to export our work from Google Docs to HTML file so we can upload it to our websites. Google Docs exported HTML file has really messy code and the body tag always has different classes like: "c47", "c72", "c21", "c38" etc. Just a "c" letter with some random number after it I guess. The main problem is that after the body tag I want to add my button (CSS button, that is not the problem though) but when I tried to use `bs4`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from bs4 import NavigableString

html = open("new_html_file.html", "w+")
soup = Soup(html, features="html.parser")
body = soup.find('body')
button = soup.new_tag('button')
button['class'] = "cupid-blue"
button['onclick'] = "location.href=\'index.html\';"
button.insert(0, NavigableString("Button text"))
body.insert_after(button)
br_line = soup.new_tag('br')
button.insert_after(br_line)

html.write(str(soup.prettify()))
html.close()
```

It says that `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert_after'` and the error is in line with `body = soup.find('body')` so basically it can't find the body tag because it seems that the body tag contains this class: "c47 c73" right? Every file has a different body tag class though, so I can't just hard code it.

My question is: **Can I insert my button tag below the body tag (it must be on top of the whole webpage) not knowing the body's tag class?**

Comment: I've never used BeautifulSoup, but if it works anything like CSS selectors, just knowing the element tag you're looking for *should* be enough, especially since there should only be one `body` in one HTML document.

Comment: Yes, I thought like that as well but that `NoneType` error shows that it can't find the body tag right? I've checked the file and it contained only one body tag so there is surely something wrong with the Python code.